# How to do t_form html5 submit

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I really need a help with this problem, being trying to fix it or find-out the solution, but couldn't find anything to help.
I have a website " www.encoregfx.com" 
Under the page you'll see Share your idea, then Send your message.
When someone fill the questions, then press send your message it does not work.
How i can make it works by sending the message to my e-mail.

I will post the code here may there is something wrong or less.

```
<form class="testim-form" HREF="popupbasic.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'stevie')">
    <div class="t_form">
        <input class="t_form1" name="name" type="text" placeholder="الاسم" data-0="opacity:1;left:0%;" data-2600="left:0%" data-3000="left:100%;" data-2000="left:100%" data-2300="left:0%;">
        <input class="t_form2" name="email" type="text" placeholder="البريد الالكتروني" data-0="opacity:1;left:0%;" data-2700="left:0%" data-3100="left:100%;" data-2050="left:100%" data-2350="left:0%;">
        <textarea class="t_form3" name="testimonials" placeholder="نص الرسالة" data-0="opacity:1;left:0%;" data-2800="left:0%" data-3200="left:100%;" data-2100="left:100%" data-2400="left:0%;"></textarea>
        <input class="t_form4" type="submit" name="ready" value="Send the message" data-0="opacity:1;left:0%;" data-2900="left:0%" data-3300="left:100%;" data-2150="left:100%" data-2450="left:0%;">
    </div>
</form>
```

I hope if someone help me with that, the theme is made by html5.

Comment: Where is the rest? So far you only have the form on display... Please display all **relevant** source code.

Comment: You have no `action=""` or `method=""` in your form, is this done in your `popup()`?

Comment: here is the code of my website this is html5 http://encoregfx.com/code.txt

in the code you will see Share your idea, and send your message, i need it to be sent to my email.

Check the code and tell me what to add?, is there other files to edit like JavaScript or css?

Answer (score 0):

The form just passes the parameters (`name`, `email` and `testimonials`) back to the web site in a `GET` http call like this:

`http://www.encoregfx.com/?name=abc&email=abc&testimonials=abc&ready=blahblah`

For it to actually send email the server would need to receive that set of parameters and act on it.  The browser won't send anything on its own.  What does your server do when it receives the request?

Comment: Yes this is the link 
http://encoregfx.com/?name=&email=&testimonials=&ready=Send+the+message

Nothing happens when i do press on send the message, it popup up the page

Comment: When you receive the new url with the name, email, etc your server needs to turn that into an email call.  I don't know what language your server is using (PHP? Java servlet?) but it needs to extract the email address and other information from the HTTP request and make some calls to send email in whatever method is appropriate on your server.  It should probably then render the HTML response as your normal web page with some kind of success message like "Your email was sent - thanks for your feedback" so the user know it worked.

Comment: Yes my server host is php 5.3 from ipage.com.
if is it hard to do that, then i will make other idea which make a button wrote " Register " then when someone press on it, it will popup new screen to fill the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Look to add both a `method` and an `action` to your form like so, I have also provided the php submit file so you can see what details have been submitted. The `data` tags have be removed just to shorten the example.

form.html

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="الاسم">
        <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="البريد الالكتروني">
        <textarea name="testimonials" placeholder="نص الرسالة"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="ready" value="Send the message">
    </div>
</form>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
    $name = ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) ) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
    $email = ( isset( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
    $testimonials = ( isset( $_POST['testimonials'] ) ) ? $_POST['testimonials'] : null;

    echo "name = " . $name . "<br>";
    echo "email = " . $email . "<br>";
    echo "testimonial = " . $testimonials;
```

Comment: To start put it in the same directory and then move on from there

Comment: Yes mate.
I changed to shorten code, and submit.php.|
I need it to be sent to my email?

Comment: I did put both in same directory and it works 100 per cent, but i need it to be sending to my email

Comment: Have a look at either `mail()` or phpmailer depending on what your host offers

Comment: Yes it works, but how i can change the email address? it works on my host  's email?

Comment: PHPMailer is a mail class that you can download and implement it can be found https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: I did added this to submit.php

Comment: // The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
mail('name@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>

Comment: Please look to open this as a separate question

Comment: Yes i am working with it, i did uploaded all files (phpmailer), what to do now?